# scipy.linalg.lu() vs scipy.linalg.lu_factor()

Tags: scipy

Aside from lu() having the option to apply the permutation matrix to the lower triangular matrix, is there any difference between these two functions?  I would appreciate insight as to which is the better, faster, and/or least likely to fail.

Answer (score 2):

There is a functional difference. Suppose you just want to have an LU decomposition; then you use `scipy.linalg.lu`. However suppose you will solve a lot of linear systems with different right hand sides. Then you obtain the low level LAPACK representations via `lu_factor` and then you use this representation in `scipy.linalg.lu_solve` function without explicitly obtaining the same LU factorization over and over again.

That would save you one `O(n^2)` operation each time you want to use the factorization in another operation down the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

*factorization* & *solution* are different aims. Factorization simplifies matrix of x coeffs with different operations, like inversion, determinant etc - giving simplier projection of lineary independent vectors (I hope).

With [lu_factor](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.lu_solve.html) further use `lu_solve` from docs:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve

A = np.array([[2, 5, 8, 7], [5, 2, 2, 8], [7, 5, 6, 6], [5, 4, 4, 8]])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
lu, piv = lu_factor(A)
x = lu_solve((lu, piv), b)
np.allclose(A @ x - b, np.zeros((4,))) 
print(x)
```

or for non-square matrix (here overdetermined system)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg import lu_factor, lu_solve

A = np.array([[2, 5, 8], [5, 2, 2], [7, 5, 6], [5, 4, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
A = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(b)),A))    # slack variable

lu, piv = lu_factor(A.T @ A)
x = lu_solve((lu, piv), A.T @ b)
print(x)
print(np.allclose(A @ x - b, np.zeros(4,)) )
print(np.linalg.norm( (A @ x - b)  -np.zeros(4,), 2))
```

for [underdetermined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55666040/solve-non-square-matrix-with-python-how-to-use-numpy-linalg-lstsq) can get many solutions & diff. solver/algo can give either

with `lu` & using `solve`

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.linalg  import solve
from scipy import  linalg

A = np.array([[2, 5, 8], [5, 2, 2], [7, 5, 6], [5, 4, 4]])
b = np.array([1, 1, 1,1])
A = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(b)),A))    # slack variable

p,l,u= linalg.lu(A)
res = solve(u, solve(l, p.T@b))
print(res)
```

p.s. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473033/why-is-scipy-linalg-lu-so-slow-for-solving-ax-b-repeatedly) are some timings

P.P.S. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2040363/comparing-lu-or-qr-decompositions-for-solving-least-squares) are some comparisons