# Solve non square matrix with python: How to use numpy.linalg.lstsq()?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra

**Requested behaviour** 
I would like to solve a non-square matrix with python. The matrix has two linearly dependent vectors.

**Current State** 
I tried to use `numpy.linalg.solve()` first, but that only works for square matrices. 
Other StackOverflow posts recommended using `numpy.linalg.lstsq()`.

**issue** 
However, I do not understand how to implement `numpy.linalg.lstsq()` correctly. The function solves the last parameter correctly, but not the other parameters. One post recommendet [this solution](https://andreask.cs.illinois.edu/cs357-s15/public/demos/06-qr-applications/Solving%20Least-Squares%20Problems.html) which I do not understand either.

Do I have to implemt a loop somehow?

> Can someone provide me with a code example? How do solve this matrix
>   problem using python?

**My current Code**

```js
import numpy as np

# defining a linear equation system E=F with
#   | -2 * x1 - 4 * x2 + 1 * x3 -  9 * x4 + 0 * x5 =  +5  |
#   |  3 * x1 + 6 * x2 + 0 * x3 + 12 * x4 + 3 * x5 = +15  |
#   |  1 * x1 + 2 * x2 + 1 * x3 +  3 * x4 + 1 * x5 = -17  |
#   | -5 * x1 - 4 * x2 + 1 * x3 -  9 * x4 + 0 * x5 = +14  |


E=np.array(
    [
        [-2,-4,1,-9,0],
        [3,6,0,12,3],
        [1,2,1,3,1],
        [-5,-10,3,-23,1]
    ]
)

F=np.array(
    [3,15,-17,14]
)

solutionNonSquare = np.linalg.lstsq(E, F)
print('the solution vector is: {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5}=')
print(solutionNonSquare)
```

**Written Matrix solution**
[image]

Comment: What answer does your code give? What answer do you expect? Your code looks correct to me, assuming that I interpreted your question correctly, except that [numpy.linalg.lstsq](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html#numpy.linalg.lstsq) returns four quantities, the first of which is the least squares solution that you want.

Comment: It returns `(array([ -4.34615385,  -8.69230769, -19.69230769,   2.30769231,
        17.5       ]), array([], dtype=float64), 3, array([3.10597849e+01, 3.82343947e+00, 8.19190114e-01, 4.91552829e-16]))`

But I would like that it returns the vector which solves the matrix system, something like `-12,5, 0, -22, 0, 17.5` or `(array([ -12,5,  0, -22,   0,
        17.5       ]),`

Comment: Is there no function or workaround which calculates the Gauss elimination method for non-square matrices?

Comment: You have 3 independent equations for 5 variables. There are many vectors that solve the system. You can add arbitrary multiples of the two null vectors to find another solution of the system. You can find *a* basis for the null space with [scipy.linalg.null_space](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html#scipy.linalg.null_space)

Comment: Could you post a code example here how you would solve the equations using scipy.linalg.null_space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an underdetermined system of equations. This means that there are many solutions, and there is no such thing as "the" solution. The fact that Gaussian elimination and `lstsq` give different solutions does not mean that anything is wrong.

Let's generate and check various solutions:

```py
import scipy.linalg as sla

E_null = sla.null_space(E)

def check_solution(coeffs):
    x = solutionNonSquare[0] + E_null @ coeffs
    check = E @ x - F
    with np.printoptions(precision=2, suppress=True):
        print('x = {}'.format(x))
    with np.printoptions(precision=5, suppress=True):
        print('E . x - F = {}'.format(check))
    print('|x| = {}'.format(np.linalg.norm(x)))
```

We can check the minimum norm solution produced by `lstsq`:

```py
>>> check_solution([0, 0])
x = [ -4.35  -8.69 -19.69   2.31  17.5 ]
E . x - F = [ 0. -0. -0.  0.]
|x| = 28.174593028253167
```

We can generate and test many other solutions

```py
>>> check_solution(100 * np.random.randn(2))
x = [ -88.93 -139.06   66.64   88.64   17.5 ]
E . x - F = [ 0.  0. -0.  0.]
|x| = 199.62363490542995
>>> check_solution(100 * np.random.randn(2))
x = [-25.2  -26.99  -5.33  16.67  17.5 ]
E . x - F = [ 0. -0. -0.  0.]
|x| = 44.455362582961335
>>> check_solution(100 * np.random.randn(2))
x = [ 93.34  14.57 -55.74 -33.74  17.5 ]
E . x - F = [ 0. -0. -0. -0.]
|x| = 116.09338153741933
```

We can even look at your solution:

```py
>>> my_favourite_solution = np.array([-12.5, 0, -22, 0, 17.5 ])
>>> my_favourite_coeffs = my_favourite_solution @ E_null
>>> check_solution(my_favourite_coeffs)
x = [-12.5   0.  -22.   -0.   17.5]
E . x - F = [ 0. -0. -0.  0.]
|x| = 30.765240125830324
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on why is it underdetermined? Assume we know all the matrices from Ax=b, where A is m by n, x is n by 1 vector, b is m by 1 vector, and we solve x . Why can't we get a result exact as x?

Comment: In this case, A is a 4x5 matrix. This means we have 4 equations for 5 variables. This can, at best, allow us to solve for 4 variables as a function of the 5th variable.

Comment: In general, when m<n it is underdetermined. If the equations are independent, when m>n it is overdetermined, when m=n there is an unique solution.